# ERROR :- from keyword not found where expected

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT A.CUSTNAME|| WHO IS HOLDING ||A.ACCNAME|| ACCOUNT ||T.TRATYPE|| THE AMOUNT ||T.AMT|| 
ON || T.t_DATE
FROM ACCOUNTHOLDER A,TRANSACTION T
ON(T.ACCNO=A.ACCNO)
WHERE  CUSTNAME='JAMES BOND'
/
```

I have two tables accountholder and transaction table where accno is common. accountholder accno is primary key and other is foreign key. I need the output in sentence form...

Comment: I'd start being making everything that should be a string a string, by putting single quotes around.

Comment: Is it mysql ? `||` used for string concatenation in Oracle, not mysql

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [CONCAT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), and your custom parts of the sentence have to be enclosed in single quotes and have the desired spaces at the beginning and at the end:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
    A.CUSTNAME,
    ' WHO IS HOLDING ',
    A.ACCNAME,
    ' ACCOUNT ',
    T.TRATYPE,
    ' THE AMOUNT ',
    T.AMT,
    ' ON ',
    T.t_DATE
    )
FROM ACCOUNTHOLDER A
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION T ON T.ACCNO = A.ACCNO
WHERE CUSTNAME = 'JAMES BOND'
```

And your JOIN wasn't right either You either use the explicit way and add INNER JOIN and ON, or you separate your tables with commas and put the condition in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper `join` syntax.  In addition to the `on` clause, you need a `join` statement.  In addition, what look like string constants should be in single quotes.  And, the proper way to concatenate strings in MySQL is to use the `concat()` function, not vertical bars:

```
SELECT concat(A.CUSTNAME, ' WHO IS HOLDING ', A.ACCNAME,  ' ACCOUNT ', 
              T.TRATYPE, ' THE AMOUNT ', T.AMT,  ' ON ', T.t_DATE)
FROM ACCOUNTHOLDER A join
     TRANSACTION T
     ON T.ACCNO=A.ACCNO 
WHERE CUSTNAME = 'JAMES BOND';
```